# Android SQLite database column data(string) get with the help of column Id

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Anyone help me for getting column data from id(INTEGER PRIMARY KEY).

My Code is Below :

```
String selectQUERY = " SELECT * FROM " + dbh.TABLE_CONTACTS.toString() +" WHERE "+ dbh.KEY_ID +"="+ "1";
Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(selectQUERY, null);
    if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
  do 
    {
    newArr.add(cr.getString(1));
    } while (cr.moveToNext());

}
for(int i=0;i<newArr.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("id pos :- "+newArr.get(i));
    }
```

Note :- newArr is a String type ArrayList.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use an ORM tools to do SQLLite in Android. Injecting code directly quickly leads to problems (http://ormlite.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much detail but it looks like you can use: `cr.getLong(0)`

```
Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(selectQUERY, null);
while (cr.moveToNext()) {
    // Do something with cr.getLong(0) here
    newArr.add(cr.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: You should have `cr.moveToFirst()` before the while loop.

Comment: `moveToNext()` does the same thing when the index is at -1 and if I use `moveToFirst()` with this loop it will skip the first entry... (Notice I switched from the do-while loop to a simpler while loop.)